# how to compare current day & month with given day & month in java

Tags: java, android, date

I want to compare current date with the given date. Current date format will be (dd-MM-YYYY). I don't want to get the current year. Suppose today's date is 30-08-2016. I want to get only 30-08, I don't want current year 2016. The given date is 15-08 and 31-08. I did not get the current date like this 30-08. How can I get this and how can I compare? Here is my code which I have tried:

```
Date date1_aug, date2_aug, cur_date;

String cur_date_string, sDay, sMonth;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");


Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);

sDay = Integer.toString(day);
sMonth = Integer.toString(month);

cur_date_string = sDay+"-"+sMonth;

            try {
                cur_date = sdf.parse(cur_date_string);
            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

1. another function:

   ```
           try{
                       date1_aug = sdf.parse("15-08");
                       date2_aug = sdf.parse("31-08");

                       if(cur_date.equals(date1_aug) || cur_date.after(date1_aug) || cur_date.before(date2_aug)){
                           textView_Amount_LateFee.setText(Config.fine_aug.get(1));
                       }


                   }catch(ParseException ex){
                       ex.printStackTrace();
                   }
   ```

Comment: `dd-MM` is not a complete date

Comment: If you want to compare the value of dd-MM (please ignore the date concept since it is not a complete date), you can compare the MM value and then dd value.

Comment: thank u. solved by ignoring date concept.

Comment: @tanzilamohita Please accept an Answer. I tried and failed to link [a duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42656159/642706) here, but could not until an Answer is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

## `java.time.MonthDay`

Use modern date-time classes in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project, an Android adaptation of [the back-port](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp) of the [java-time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. Avoid the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

These java.time classes include the [`MonthDay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) class to represent a month and a day-of-month without a year.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.of( 8 , 15 );
```

This class already implements the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and its [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html#compareTo-java.time.MonthDay-) method. Also implements methods [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html#isBefore-java.time.MonthDay-), and [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html#isAfter-java.time.MonthDay-). So, job done.

Determining the [current `MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) requires a time zone. For any given moment the date varies by [time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
MonthDay today = MonthDay.now( z );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the same year in the dates you want to compare?

Just using Calendar, set the year to be the same in the two Date objects and after that compare them...

(Take care with the leap-years)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the year, forget about using the date concept itself.

```
String given_date = "15-08";

String[] tokens = given_date.split("-");

int given_day = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
int given_month = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

int now_month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int now_day = c.get(Calendar.DATE);

System.out.println(given_day + " " + given_month + " " + now_day + " " + now_month);

if (now_month > given_month) {
    System.out.println("Before Today!");
} else if (now_month < given_month) {
    System.out.println("After Today!");
} else {
    if (now_day > given_day) {
        System.out.println("Before Today!");
    } else if (now_day < given_day) {
        System.out.println("After Today!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Today!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function to check dob( with current date)
/** dob should be in the format yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss */
public static boolean isTodayBdy(String dob) {
    Date today = new Date();
    try {
        if(dob.length() > 1){
            Date dobDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse(dob);
            if ((today.getMonth() == dobDate.getMonth()) && (today.getDate() == dobDate.getDate())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```